# How to set custom HTTP response headers in Next.js without using a custom server?

Tags: javascript, http-headers, next.js

I am working on a Next.js application, and I would like to add a custom HTTP response header to *all* pages (I don't need it to be configurable *per* page).

Now I was wondering how to do that, *without* having to set up a custom server. Is this even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's probably not possible without tradeoffs. Next.js has Automatic Static Optimization, so pages that can be statically exported will be exported to plain `.html` files. And `.html` files require no code execution on a server so there is no place to add a custom HTTP header.

Alternatively, you could add custom HTTP headers on every response with `getServerSideProps` in `_app.js`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  // set HTTP header
  context.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

But **having `getServerSideProps` would disable static optimization** as all pages will be only server-side rendered.

[Server-side Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

Comment: This is the way, if you are deploying to Vercel

Comment: `context.res.setHeader('toast', 'some message')` hasn't been working for me. Even calling `console.log('headers', context.res.getHeaders());` in the next line doesn't show my new header. Can you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72190692/how-can-i-show-a-toast-notification-when-redirecting-due-to-lack-of-session-usin?noredirect=1#comment127573841_72201657 Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 16):

For Next.js versions 9.5 and after you can define custom headers in your `next.config.js` file.

The following config would apply a custom header to all static and server-rendered pages.

```js
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      { 
        source: '/:path*{/}?',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-custom-header',
            value: 'my custom header value for all pages',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

[See next.config.js Headers](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers)

Currently matching all pages is a little unintuitive. As seen in the example above it requires the syntax `'/:path*{/}?'`. This is currently tracked in [GitHub Issue #14930](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/14930).

Comment: This won't work on Vercel because it will overwrite Cache-Control headers set in next.config.js in production to ensure that  static assets can be cache effectively