# In Next.js pages router, what is the effect of client-side navigation + getServerSideProps + res.setHeader?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In Next.js (pages router), in getServerSideProps you have access to the response object, so you can set headers for the response. I have seen this used to set headers on the page response (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61814207/674487)).

However, Next.js can do client-side navigation, that is, if you use `<Link>` in a page (in pages router), when the user clicks on it the page will be rendered client-side and getServerSideProps will be called only to get the data (i.e. json) from the client.

I understand that client-side navigation would defeat the ability to set page headers (e.g. Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy) in getServerSideProps. **Is that correct?**

P.S.: I am aware that headers can be set in `next.config.js` ([docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/headers)) and that [it is possible to set headers in a middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/middleware#setting-headers).